# AJAX and Jquery auto form update not working

Tags: jquery, sql, json, ajax, wordpress

This is what I have on the form page:

```
<form action = "/register-process" method = "post" id="form1">
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(document).on('focusout', '#dateenglish', function () {
    var dateenglish = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/wp-content/themes/yahrzeit-theme/getdate.php',
        data: {
            'dateenglish': dateenglish
        },
        success:function(data) {
            // This outputs the result of the ajax request
            $('#dateenglish').val(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
<input id = "dateenglish" class="form_area" required name = "dateenglish" required type = "text" value="<?= $date; ?>" />
<input id = "datehebrew" class="form_area" required name = "datehebrew" required type = "text" value="<?= $date; ?>"  />
</form>
```

And this is what I have in the getpage.php:

```
<?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php' );
// Do the following if the form submits
if (isset($_REQUEST['dateenglish'])) {
$date = $_REQUEST['dateenglish'];

global $wpdb;

$stmt = "SELECT
heb_date,
greg_date
FROM calendar
WHERE greg_date = '".$date."'
OR heb_date = '".$date."'
";

$myrows = $wpdb->get_results($stmt);

// Not sure if its an array that is returned, but this will get the first value.
$row = current($myrows);

// Let's check which date is different
if ($date != $row['greg_date']) {
    $date = $row['greg_date'];
} else {
    $date = $row['heb_date'];
}

echo $date;
} else {
echo 'error';
}
?>
```

All I am trying to do is get the form to look up a date array from the table "calendar" from user input, check it against the database, and return the corresponding value from row 2 into the other field, AND VICE-VERSA.

I.E. someone types in one thing, it checks, adds the other then it stays. Right now it doesn't stay in the field. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Issue with $.ajax Call,
i have checked your ajax call and found that your application not accepting GET url so add one more parameter to your `$.ajax` call `method : "POST"`  and it will work.

You can try below code

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).on('focusout', '#dateenglish', function () {
        var dateenglish = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/wp-content/themes/yahrzeit-theme/getdate.php',
            method : "POST",
            data: {
                'dateenglish': dateenglish
            },
            success:function(data) {
                // This outputs the result of the ajax request
                $('#dateenglish').val(data);
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
    });
```

update Php

```
    <?php
    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php' );
    // Do the following if the form submits
    if (isset($_REQUEST['dateenglish'])) {
    $date = $_REQUEST['dateenglish'];

    global $wpdb;

    $stmt = "SELECT
    heb_date,
    greg_date
    FROM calendar
    WHERE greg_date = '".$date."'
    OR heb_date = '".$date."'
    ";

    $myrows = $wpdb->get_results($stmt);

    // Not sure if its an array that is returned, but this will get the first value.

    while ($row = $myrows->fetch_field()){
        // Let's check which date is different
        if ($date != $row['greg_date']) {
            $date = $row['greg_date'];
        } else {
            $date = $row['heb_date'];
        }
        echo $date;
        return;
    }




    } else {
    echo 'error';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: The date just disappears on focus out. Weird

Comment: tat may be becoz of `$data` would be empty. check your database records.

Comment: There isn't a $data row in the table, they are named "greg_date" and "heb_date"

Comment: can you write value of one database record here ?

Comment: Yes the database goes as follows: the headers are heb_date and greg_date. '3rd of Av 5782', '7/31/2022'